# relation between Metric spaces and the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Is $\Bbb C \subset$ M ,where M is a metric space?
If so, then every theorem,proof,etc. that works on M can be applied in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: $\mathbb C$ with its natural euclidean distance is a metric space, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes(*), that's the point with abstraction like metric space. You prove things using abstract metric space and then it will be applicable to every metric space. $\mathbb C$ is a metric space with the euclidean distance $d(z,w) = |z-w|$ as a metric.

(*) $\mathbb C$ is in fact a metric space in it's own right and you need not say that it's a subset, but in fact every subset of a metric space is itself a metric space with the same metric (if you need your metric space to be non-empty you need the subset to be that as well) which is easily verified.